# force "Save As" a data url

Tags: javascript, html, download, save, savefiledialog

I'm making a web app where the user creates some text and needs to save that to the user's computer. The saving works, but it just dumps the file in to the download folder with it's default name, and that's not very application-like.

This is my save code:

```
var download_link = document.createElement("a");
download_link.href = "data:application/json," + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(obj));
download_link.download = "model.json";
download_link.target = "_blank";
document.body.appendChild(download_link);
download_link.click();
document.body.removeChild(download_link);
```

So is there a way to force most browsers to "Save as" instead of just the browsers default download behaviour?

Comment: Because you don't want the download to use the default filename?

Comment: No, I want it to have a save as popup where you can select the file name and location.